# Openxlsx: how to save worksheet to file?

Tags: r, openxlsx

I am trying to learn the `openxlsx` package in R. I can load an Excel file into a workbook using `loadWorkbook()`. So far, so good. When I try to save this workbook to disk using `saveWorkbook()`, I am presented with the following error message:

```
    Error in write_worksheet_xml_2(prior = prior, post = post, sheet_data = ws$sheet_data,  :
    CHAR() can only be applied to a 'CHARSXP', not a 'NULL'
```

The same happens when I use the original name (and the `overwrite = TRUE` option), try to save to a new file, with or without editing the file contents.

I'm on

- macOS 10.14.6,
- R 4.0.2,
- Rstudio 1.3.1093, and
- openxlsx 4.2.3.

Can anyone here help me find a solution? I cannot tell from the error message where to start looking for a solution. Searching the web did not give useful results.

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question because I had the same problem.

After a lot of trial and error, I realised that this problem could be traced back to the fact that various rows in my excel-file were grouped (using excels group-function). After deleting these groupings, adding a sheet to an existing workbook with the regular procedure worked without any problems:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("myfile.xlsx")
writeData(wb, sheet = "mysheet", mydataframe)
saveWorkbook(wb, "myfile.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```

I hope this answer can help someone who's also facing this problem :)

Comment: Thanks! Will see if this solves my problem as soon as I find the time. Would be very annoying, as I am trying to automate a workflow. Ungrouping manually in Excel is a pain.

Comment: Agreed! But if your error is also due to groupings, you can remove them with the command `ungroupRows`, so that you could still automate your workflow. (if you still need groupings in your excel-output, you should be able to insert them with the command `groupRows`)